# MIPS "la" pseudo instruciton

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In MIPS, the `la` instruction translates into `lui` and `ori`. However, MARS Simulator does not seem to do that at all. When I dump the following machine code:

```
.text
    la $a0, array
    la $a1, array_size
    lw $a1, 0($a1)

.data
    array: .word 0:10
    array_size: .word 10
    message: .asciiz "The sum of numbers in array is: "
```

I get:

```
00100000000001000010000000000000
00100000000001010010000000101000
10001100101001010000000000000000
```

Which is obviously. It is dumping `la` as one instruction. What does MARS do? How can I make it interpret `la` as `lui` and `ori`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's happening here is that your assembler is compiling these `la`s as `addi $<dest>, $0, <value>`. The two-instruction sequence is only required for values which can't be represented in a 16-bit immediate; the values you're using here look like `0x2000` and `0x2028`, so they fit in a single instruction.

> How can I make it interpret `la` as `lui` and `ori`?

Load bigger constants. `:)` Your assembler might also have an option to force the use of the full sequence even when it's unnecessary.